# Best way to convince boss remote working is the way to go?

Tags: telecommute

I'm a programmer and I work in an office. I work in an office that outsources most programming work to asia. I don't really know why but I've been told that the boss doesn't want me to work remotely. This seems odd as only 2 members of a staff of 7 are in the office.

Basically the wages in our area aren't keeping up with the cost of living and I'd like to live in a cheaper community.

What can I do to convince him that programmers should be allowed to work remotely?

Comment: I see no reason why programmers inherently should work remotely and in fact I have had to have some people brought back in from remote work because they were far less productive. So you need a far better argument than, I want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Often times companies are afraid of remote work because they've never done it before, and the unknown is scary. It puts more work on your manager/HR team to develop a strategy for making remote work successful.

My recommendation is to put together a plan with potential pros/cons of working remotely. Highlight how the pros will save the company time/money/turnover/etc, and how you plan to deal with the cons to ensure it's painless for your manager & company overall.

You can reference this article for ways to make remote work succesful:
https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/29/making-remote-work-behind-scenes/

Comment: Thanks that article was similar to the advice I was looking for. If you have any more reading, I'd love to see it.